# yii2 запуск команды из модуля через консоль

Tags: php, yii2

Не удается правильно запустить из консоли команду модуля

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю следующим образом:

```
./yii iiko/import/import-contacts-first
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
Unknown command: iiko/import/import-contacts-first
```

Как правильно запустить экшн данного контроллера?

Comment: а зачем `./` вначале?

Comment: В `common/config/console.php` прописан ваш модуль?

Comment: А и маршрут должен быть такой `crm/iiko/import/import-contacts-first`